# MAILTO: Form Action Alternative?

Tags: php, html, css

So, I want to set up a feedback section on my site, and the code seemed to work just fine in w3school's [TryIt Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic) but for some reason it didn't work on my site.

I found another question, also here on stack overflow which is pretty similar but I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28970341/6125445)...

> mailto: form actions depend on browsers and local email clients playing together nicely. They do this so rarely that mailto: form actions are unusable on the WWW.
>
> Replace it with a server side program that sends the email.

Could someone possibly give an example of what this meant? It was pretty vague, I'm assuming they meant something like PHP, but I'm not quite sure.

CSS:

```
.form-style-1 {
margin:10px auto;
max-width: 400px;
padding: 20px 12px 10px 20px;
font: 13px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
.form-style-1 li {
  padding: 0;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
.form-style-1 label{
  margin:0 0 3px 0;
  padding:0px;
  display:block;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
.form-style-1 input[type=text], 
.form-style-1 input[type=date],
.form-style-1 input[type=datetime],
.form-style-1 input[type=number],
.form-style-1 input[type=search],
.form-style-1 input[type=time],
.form-style-1 input[type=url],
.form-style-1 input[type=email],
textarea, 
select{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border:1px solid #BEBEBE;
  padding: 7px;
  margin:0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;  
  }
.form-style-1 input[type=text]:focus, 
.form-style-1 input[type=date]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=datetime]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=number]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=search]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=time]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=url]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type=email]:focus,
.form-style-1 textarea:focus, 
.form-style-1 select:focus{
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #88D5E9;
  border: 1px solid #88D5E9;
  }
.form-style-1 .field-divided{
  width: 49%;
  }
.form-style-1 .field-long{
  width: 100%;
  }
.form-style-1 .field-select{
  width: 100%;
  }
.form-style-1 .field-textarea{
  height: 100px;
  }
.form-style-1 input[type=submit], .form-style-1 input[type=button]{
  background: #4B99AD;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  }
.form-style-1 input[type=submit]:hover, .form-style input[type=button]:hover{
  background: #4691A4;
  box-shadow:none;
  -moz-box-shadow:none;
  -webkit-box-shadow:none;
  }
.form-style-1 .required{
  color:red;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="MAILTO:feedback@itzjavacraft.tk" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
      <ul class="form-style-1">
        <li>
          <label>
            Full Name <span class="required">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" name="field1" class="field-divided" placeholder="First"/>&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="field2" class="field-divided" placeholder="Last"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            Email <span class="required">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="email" name="field3" class="field-long" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          Subject
        </label>
        <select name="field4" class="field-select">
          <option value="Feedback">Feedback</option>
          <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
          <option value="General">General</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          Your Message <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <textarea name="field5" id="field5" class="field-long field-textarea"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Replace it with a server side program that sends the email.

Means, mailto will not work, you need to use any server side
programs to process the email like PHP mail function.
Example:

```
<?php
  $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
  $subject = 'the subject';
  $message = 'hello';
  $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com';
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Learn detail about PHP mail function from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)
You can retrive data from the form and use in the mail function of PHP.

Comment: This is only a partial answer and doesn't completely solve the question; you missed something in their code.