# Why mailto isn't working in action attribute of my form tag?

Tags: html, forms, web

I am working on a html form. I added mailto for action attribute but it is not working

(I am using an android code editor)

Here's the output

[image]

And in android chrome, nothing happens on clicking submit button

```html
<p>Wanna get in touch…?</p>
<ul>
  <li><strong>Telegram:</strong> Swayam355</li>
  <li><strong>Instagram:</strong> swayam._.bansal</li>
  <li><strong>E-mail:</strong> sytgaming355@gmail.com</li>

</ul>
<p>Or fill out this form</p>
<form class="" action="mailto:swayambansal355@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="yourName" value="">

  <br>

  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="Email" value="">

  <br>

  <label>Your Image</label>
  <input type="file" name="Image" value=""><br>
  <label>Your Message</label><br>
  <textarea name="Message" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit">

  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML form email using mailto in form action doesnt work in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970287/html-form-email-using-mailto-in-form-action-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Remove the space from your email. No space after mailto: - if the client does not have email configured, your mail will fail too

Comment: There isn't any space already

Comment: The snippet is working alright from my system

Comment: Ok Rana. Thanks for informing me. I think I didn't make any mistake with the code. I may be able to achieve it over all the systems and browsers with JavaScript which I'll learn in future.